# Calling functions through arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am in the middle of writing a program which has a function which runs another function:

```
int executePuzzle(int input) {
    switch (input) {
        case 1: puzzle1();break;
        case 2: puzzle2();break;
        default:break;
    }
}
```

However it may be more efficient to simply have something like:

```
int puzzle[2] = {puzzle1(),puzzle2()};
```

Then call puzzle0; I was wondering how this would be done.

Comment: What did you try? What is your question? You could return from a function a `struct` containing e.g. an array, or you could return a heap-allocated array...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like a place where function pointers would be useful

```
typedef void (*puzzlePointer)();
puzzlePointer puzzles[] = { puzzle1, puzzle2, puzzle3 };

void executePuzzle(int input) {
  if (input >= 0 && input < 2) {
    puzzles[input]();
  }
}
```

Comment: As long as the input is 0 or 1, this will work. If the input is anything else then bad things will happen (unless you add input-checking code).

Comment: @mah very true, mostly I was trying to get accross the concept. I'll add error handling.

Comment: Should be `input < 2` since 2 indexes beyond the array.

Comment: @mah yes, once again another example of why I shouldn't post here until i've finished my morning coffee.

Comment: +1: warning: executePuzzle doesn't return a 'int'. It's a joke. lol

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Function Pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 0):

When the cases of the `switch` statement are contiguous like in your `executePuzzle` function, it is actually likely that the compiler internally uses function pointers (through a jump table) to implement the `switch` statement.